# How to create a tab-like registration form in Ionic 2 & 3

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I am creating a registration form in ionic and would like to have the registration page split into different tabs. what i mean is to have the user click on "Next" after filling the information on the first page and so on to the last page before submitting the form. Any pointers or assistance will be highly appreciated.

I am pretty much a beginner with ionic 2 & 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are finding for Ionic Slides. You can achieve your target by using this.
Please check this.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/

you can lock the sliding by parameter `shouldLockSwipeToNext`. Then user will not be able to swipe to the next slide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dilanka. Can i use this for forms? and also pass parameters?

Comment: please describe your requirement? What do yo mean by passing parameters? I suggest you go through the API. I have given the URL for that... :) don't be lazy to read the API ;)